# Differentiability of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[-1,1]$ and twice differentiable on $(-1,1)$. Let $\varphi(x) = (f(x) - f(0))/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $\varphi(0) = f'(0)$. Show that $\varphi$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and differentiable on $(-1,1)$. By using a second order mean value theorem for $f$ show that $\varphi'(x) = f''(\frac{\theta x}{2})$ for some $\theta \in (0,1)$. Hence prove there exists $c \in (-1,1)$ such that $f'(c) = f(-1) + f(1) - 2f(0)$.

So for $x\neq 0$ it's easy to see that $\varphi$ is continuous and differentiable. We have $\varphi(x) \to \varphi(0) = f'(0)$ as $x\to 0$ by differentiability of $f$. So $\phi$ is continuous at $0$.

We have $$\frac{\phi(h) - \phi(0)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} - f'(0)\right)$$

now I'd very much like to say that as $h\to 0$ we have the inside bracket going to $0$ as well so the entire thing goes to $0$, but that doesn't work since there's a $1/h$ to take into account as well. So this seems like a prime time to pull out L'Hopital (I'm not sure if this is rigorous or not) so we get $$\frac{\frac{hf'(h) - f(h) + f(0)}{h^2}}{1}$$ but this seems to make matters even worse.

As for the other parts, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The assumption is that $f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ and differentiable on $(-1,1)$.  Yet, the second part states "By using a second-order mean value theorem ...," which indicates that $f$ is twice differentiable.  So, does $f''$ exist?  Is $f''$ continuous on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Oops, missed the word "twice" in $f$ is *twice* differentiable on $(-1,1)$. All fixed now.

Comment: Regarding differentiability of $\phi$ note that $f$ is differentiable (e.g. on $x=0$) iff
$$f(x)-f(0)= f^\prime(0)x + o(|x|)$$
where $o(|x|)$ is a function such that $\frac{o(|x|)}{|x|}\rightarrow 0 $ when $x\rightarrow 0$. Divide by $x$ and you get the differentiability of $\phi$ in $0$.

Comment: @Thomas Dividing by $x$ and letting $x\to 0$ only gives that $f'(0)=f'(0)$

Comment: @ZainPatel Is $f''$ continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Whe have
\begin{equation}
\frac {\phi(h)-\phi(0)} {h}  = \frac {1} {h} \left ( \frac {f(h) - f(0)} {h} - f'(0) \right ) = \frac {f(h) - f(0) - hf'(0)} {h^2}.
\end{equation}

If you apply L'Hopital rule on the last quotient (of the above equation), it is easy to see that you can, you find (where we used the differentiability of $f'$ for the very last step of the equation below)
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {\phi(h)-\phi(0)} {h}  = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(h) - f(0) - hf'(0)} {h^2} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f'(h) - f'(0)} {2h} = \frac 12 f''(0).
\end{equation}

So $\phi$ is differentiable at $0$ and $\phi'(0) = \frac 12 f''(0)$.

(text) = edit.

Comment: You have assumed that $f''$ is continuous at $0$.  That isn't given.

Comment: At which step did I assume it ?

Comment: The last step. Why should $f''(h)/2 \to f''(0/2)$ as $h \to 0$?

Comment: You assumed that $\lim_{h\to 0}f''(h)=f''(0)$.

Comment: Oh I see from where the confusion comes, i shall edit to make clear what I meant.

Comment: He is only using that $f''(0)$ exists.